# Using Submodules Within SpringLemon

Tags: spring-lemon

I want to make use to the exception handling features within SpringLemon.  Do I need to include all of SpringLemon (i.e. the main library and other configuration elements)

I've tried creating the example project and removed some of the dependent properties in application.yml

What I saw was exceptions to provide URL for a datasource even though I am not making use of anything database related.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, just use the exceptions module, as documented at https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/wiki/Spring-Lemon-Exceptions-Guide